# How to suppress "match is not exhaustive!" warning in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

How can I suppress the "match is not exhaustive!" warning in the following Scala code?

```
val l = "1" :: "2" :: Nil
l.sliding(2).foreach{case List(a,b) => }
```

The only solution that I found so far is to surround the pattern matching with an additional match statement:

```
l.sliding(2).foreach{x => (x: @unchecked) match {case List(a,b) => }}
```

However this makes the code unnecessarily complex and pretty unreadable.  So there must be a shorter and more readable alternative.  Does someone know one?

### Edit

I forgot to mention that my list `l` has at least 2 elements in my program.  That's why I can safely suppress the warning.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here are several options:

1. You can match against `Seq` instead of `List`, since `Seq` doesn't have the exhaustiveness checking (this will fail, like your original, on one element lists):

   ```
   l.sliding(2).foreach{case Seq(a, b) => ... }
   ```
2. You can use a for comprehension, which will silently discard anything that doesn't match (so it will do nothing on one element lists):

   ```
   for (List(a, b) <- l.sliding(2)) { ... }
   ```
3. You can use `collect`, which will also silently discard anything that doesn't match (and where you'll get an iterator back, which you'll have to iterate through if you need to):

   ```
   l.sliding(2).collect{case List(a,b) => }.toList
   ```

Comment: I disagree with this. It is obviously a solution, but a bad one. It its non-obvious that Seq is used to suppress exhaustiveness checks when the code is read.

Comment: I agree that solutions 1 and 2 make it non-obvious that exhaustiveness checks are being suppressed, but solution 3 is pretty explicit about it by using `collect`.

Comment: I agree with you. My complaint was directed against 1.

Answer (score 20):

Making it complete with `; case _ => ???` is pretty short.  `???` just throws an exception.  You can define your own if you're using 2.9 or before (it's new in 2.10).

It really is pretty short compared to what you need for a match annotation:

```
(: @unchecked)
; case _ => ???
              ^  One more character!
```

It doesn't throw a `MatchError`, but does that really matter?

Comment: I agree.  This is nearly as short as the @unchecked solution but IMO more readable.  Thanks.  PS: the new ??? function is pretty nice.

Comment: The semicolon is not necessary. The compiler already have `case` and `=>` as separator symbols. And if the default case can never be reached, it is necessary to write `case _ =>`.

Comment: @sschaef - I was assuming that (1) you wanted it easy to visually parse (hence, with a `;`), and (2) you wanted an exception thrown if you were wrong about the match completeness (hence with `???`).  You're right that it can be even shorter if either of those are not true.  (Personally I find case statements on the same line without a `;` separator look like gobbledygook.)

Comment: I don't like this solution because `???` is canonically used to represent code that has not been written yet. If you use it for other purposes, then you muddle this meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Since your `sliding(2)` can possibly return one last list with only one element in it, you should also test it:

```
l sliding(2) foreach {
  case a::b::Nil => println("two elements: " + a + b)
  case l         => println("one last element" + l.head)
}
```

Comment: Good example what exhaustiveness checks are for.

Comment: `sliding` does not return one element lists when `step` is one. However, you would have to check when moving the window by more than one on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
implicit class RichAny[A](private val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  @inline
  def match_ignoring_nonexhaustive[B](f: PartialFunction[A,B]): B = f(a)
}
```

With this you could do the following, which actually only interprets the case match as PartialFunction:

```
l.sliding(2).foreach{ _ match_ignoring_nonexhaustive {case List(a,b) => }}
```