# How to avoid "Match is not exhaustive" when just one "case" is needed?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to suppress “match is not exhaustive!” warning in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229930/how-to-suppress-match-is-not-exhaustive-warning-in-scala)

```
object Euler extends App {
val Max = 4000000

def p2: Int = p2(0 :: 1 :: Nil).filter(_ % 2 == 0).sum

def p2(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    list match {
        case n1 :: n2 :: tail => if (Max < n1) n2 :: tail
                                 else p2(n1 + n2 :: list)
        // case _ => 0 :: 0 :: Nil // "match is not exhaustive"
    }
}   
println(p2)
}
```

Can someone perhaps show me an example that explains how to make my snippet compilable without the second case?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`@unchecked`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/unchecked.html):

```
(list: @unchecked) match { ... }
```

Answer (score 6):

If just one case is needed, then seeing other cases would signify an error. I'd add `case _` that raises an error. It would fire if you passed a list less than 2 elements long, for instance.

Alternatively, you can manually cut list's head twice, though it won't be as concise.

Comment: Scala already raises an error if no case matches.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: if you don't mind your code bombing at runtime instead of failing to compile, you could as well use a dynamic language. This may be OK for a project Euler snippet, but I'd be very sad seeing such an approach in production code.

Comment: @Alexei Romanov: while this observation is true, this does not mean that raising an exception by hand is bad. Matching the default case and throwing an error gives the opportunity to raise a more meaningful error, and explicitly asserts that this case is invalid (failed prereq) as opposed to simply have forgotten to handle a valis case.

Comment: @9000 your code will bomb at runtime as well, if I got your idea right (throw an error in *other* branch), or will not just run e.g. if you place only `case _`, without arrow, or will swallow invalid situation (case _ => ). I do believe that generally the first one or MatchException should be preferred.

Comment: Sounds like "val n1 :: n2 :: tail = list" + "if..else" is not as "unsmart" as I thought... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: yes, there seems to be no way to easily describe a list of not less than two elements using Scala's type system, so static checking will not help this particular case. Having an explicit branch that says 'our logic fails here' seems better to me than smoothly-looking code which is guaranteed to crash you don't know where.

Comment: @9000 Yes, there is: see http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/NonEmptyList.scala.html.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: good to know, thanks! Probably this can be parametrized to 'at-least-N-elements-List', too.